# Is there a simple java program that can extract URL & title of html files

Tags: java, html, xml

Hi I am looking for a simple URL & title extractor from html files in Java. I am trying to parse bookmarks.html (IE,Firefox) etc and add the title & url to a db. I need to do this in java (no 3rd party libraries allowed) so proably I have to use sax/dom/regex.

Comment: Are the HTML files well-formed XML?  If not, then you won't be able to parse them using the JAXP parsers.  You'd be forced to use a third party package like Tag Soup (http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/).

Comment: I belive they are well formatted as they are being generated from browser export. I am going to bite the bullet and start writing SAX route (as my target platform needs very small physical and memory foot-print) you guessed it it's for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can load up the file into a DOM document and then use an XPath expression to find all the instances of an  tag.  Extracting the HREF attribute and the tag contents should do what you want to do.  The XPath would probably be something as simple as `'//A'`.